# why my speech recognition program is not working even after code is correct?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio, google-speech-api

I'm trying to make my own assistant like google assistant with python. My speech recognition program was working previously but after cleaning some junk files from the computer it is not working, it is stuck on "Speak:" and not converting speech into text, not even showing any error.

I have installed pyaudio, speechrecognition.

This is the code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr  

r = sr.Recognizer()                                                                                   
with sr.Microphone() as source:                                                                       
    print("Speak:")                                                                                   
    audio = r.listen(source)   
try:
    print("You said " + r.recognize_google(audio))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results; {0}".format(e))
```

Comment: It sounds like the definition of "clean some junk files" may be very important. Were there python or system files included in those you removed?

Comment: i don't know. Razer cortex software did this cleaning thing.